# Как напечатать лишь одну(закрывающую скобку) без ошибок?

Tags: latex

Мне необходима закрывающая скобка после буквы "б)".

Однако компилятор не воспринимает ее и просто игнорирует

Comment: Приведите пример, как пишете, что компилятор игнорирует - скорее всего, у Вас ошибка в другом месте. Круглые скобки можно употреблять по одной штуке без каких-либо побочных эффектов.